# Can I set a fixed length for MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm extending `BinaryWriter` using a `MemoryStream`.

```
public class PacketWriter : BinaryWriter
{
    public PacketWriter(Opcode op) : base(CreateStream(op))
    {
        this.Write((ushort)op);
    }

    private static MemoryStream CreateStream(Opcode op) {
        return new MemoryStream(PacketSizes.Get(op));
    }

    public WriteCustomThing() {
        // Validate that MemoryStream has space?
        // Do all the stuff
    }
}
```

Ideally, I want to use write using `PacketWriter` as long as there is space available (which is already defined in `PacketSizes`). If there isn't space available, I want an exception thrown. It seems like `MemoryStream` just dynamically allocates more space if you write over capacity, but I want a fixed capacity. Can I achieve this without needing to check the length every time? The only solution I thought of so far was to override all the `Write` methods of `BinaryWriter` and compare lengths, but this is annoying.

Comment: Looking at the source for MemoryStream, if you provide the buffer then it won't expand automatically.

Comment: @mikez Hey! That sounds like it could work. To be clear, I would need to use a definition that includes `index` and `count` right? Like `MemoryStream(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)`

Comment: I haven't checked it myself but it looks like any of the constructors that take a byte[] buffer would set the expandable field to false.

Comment: @mikez Cool. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just provide a buffer of the desired size to write into:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[3];
        var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        stream.WriteByte(1);
        stream.WriteByte(2);
        stream.WriteByte(3);
        Console.WriteLine("Three successful writes");
        stream.WriteByte(4); // This throws
        Console.WriteLine("Four successful writes??");
    }
}
```

This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=netstandard-1.6#System_IO_MemoryStream__ctor_System_Byte___) behavior:

> Initializes a new **non-resizable** instance of the MemoryStream class based on the specified byte array.

Comment: Sorry I know this was a long time ago, but what if I want to not throw an exception, but handle the case of the buffer being full. (For example sending the buffer to a native api that doesn't understand .net streams)

Comment: @gyozokudor: I suggest you ask a new question with more details of what you're trying to do.